# How to achieve such search bar effect when scrolling in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

What I want to do is for the search bar to remain visible while scrolling down like that:[video](https://www.tumblr.com/blog/view/skyune/691844613080809472?source=share)

Comment: Use stickyHeader in LazyColumn for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by implementing collapsing Toolbar

here is a article if you want to implement it yourself: [Collapsing Toolbar in Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/kotlin-and-kotlin-for-android/collapsing-toolbar-in-jetpack-compose-codebase-e46f92d8b510)

here is a library that you can use:  [onebone /
compose-collapsing-toolbar](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar)